# Oracle Query to retrieve records when one of the conditions is true but not when both are true

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-operator

I have the following table and I want to retrieve students (`STUD_ID`) who have taken either `ENGLISH` or `SCIENCE`. If they have taken *both* ENGLISH and SCIENCE, then do not retrieve.

So the desired output is 101,102,104,106,107

The table is actually a View with the first 2 columns from the table `STUD_INFO` and the subject column are from a **Nested table** within the STUD_INFO table.

```
SELECT groupid, 
       Stud_id, 
       NST.Name
  FROM STUD_INFO, 
       TABLE(SUBINFO) NST
```

Can anyone help me with a SQL query? The interesting part is when I use 
Subject = ENGLISH and Subject = Science it does not retrieve any data.

```
groupid Stud_id Subject
-------   -------   --------
1   101 ENGLISH
1   102 MATH
1   103 ENGLISH
1   103 SCIENCE
1   104 ENGLISH
1   104 MATH
1   105 PT
1   105 ENGLISH
1   105 SCIENCE
2   106 ENGLISH
2   107 SCIENCE
2   108 SCIENCE
2   108 ENGLISH
```

Comment: Don't use tabs when posting code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Subject = ENGLISH and Subject = SCIENCE` says "Subject needs to be both ENGLISH and SCIENCE **at the same time**" which can never be true.

```
select stud_id from your_view
where subject in ('ENGLISH', 'SCIENCE')
group by stud_id
having count(subject) = 1
```

Does this work for you?